# Oracle query using more temp space than usual

Tags: sql, oracle

One of our customers informs us that a process cannot complete because they run out of temp space (20GB). The process is part of standard software and we usually need no more than 300MB of temp space.

We started to monitor the temp space (Metalink note: 364417.1) and found the offending query. We also ran the process with sql trace on, both on our clients database and on our database. 
(Both Oracle 10.2.0.5, exact same version of our application, exact same data)

Here is the difference:

Trace from our database:

```
SELECT OBC1.BCT_ID BCT_ID 
FROM
 NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT OBC1 ,NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT OBC2 ,NGG_OBJECT 
  OBJ1 ,NGG_OBJECT OBJ2 ,NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT LBC1 ,NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT 
  LBC2 WHERE OBC1.BCT_ID = OBC2.BCT_ID AND OBC1.OBJ_ID = OBJ1.ID AND 
  OBC2.OBJ_ID = OBJ2.ID AND OBJ1.ODE_ID IS NULL AND OBJ2.ODE_ID IS NULL AND 
  OBC1.LBC_ID = LBC1.ID AND OBC2.LBC_ID = LBC2.ID AND OBJ1.ID > OBJ2.ID AND 
  OBJ1.TRE_ID_V IS NULL AND OBJ2.TRE_ID_V IS NULL AND LBC1.LDE_ID = :B2 AND 
  LBC1.LDE_ID = LBC2.LDE_ID AND OBJ1.TRE_ID_O = :B1 AND LBC1.FOUT = 0


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse       24      0.01       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute     26      0.04       0.04          0          0          0           0
Fetch       26      0.15       0.14          0      11932          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total       76      0.21       0.18          0      11932          0           0

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Misses in library cache during execute: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 63     (recursive depth: 2)

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=181 us)
      0   NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=155 us)
      0    NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=133 us)
      0     NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=110 us)
      0      NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=91 us)
      0       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECT (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=65 us)
      0        INDEX RANGE SCAN NGG_OBJ_TRE_FK_O_I (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=40 us)(object id 49579)
      0       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0        INDEX RANGE SCAN NGG_OBC_OBJ_FK_I (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49586)
      0      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0       INDEX RANGE SCAN NGG_OBC_BCT_FK_I (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49585)
      0     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN NGG_OBJ_PK (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49596)
      0    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN NGG_LBC_PK (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49591)
      0   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN NGG_LBC_PK (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49591)

********************************************************************************
```

The trace from our clients database is the same except for the amount of rows fetched:

```
********************************************************************************

SELECT OBC1.BCT_ID BCT_ID 
FROM
 NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT OBC1 , NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT OBC2 , NGG_OBJECT 
  OBJ1 , NGG_OBJECT OBJ2 , NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT LBC1 , 
  NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT LBC2   WHERE OBC1.BCT_ID =  OBC2.BCT_ID  AND 
  OBC1.OBJ_ID =  OBJ1.ID  AND OBC2.OBJ_ID =  OBJ2.ID  AND OBJ1.ODE_ID IS NULL 
    AND OBJ2.ODE_ID IS NULL   AND OBC1.LBC_ID =  LBC1.ID  AND OBC2.LBC_ID =  
  LBC2.ID  AND OBJ1.ID >  OBJ2.ID  AND OBJ1.TRE_ID_V IS NULL   AND 
  OBJ2.TRE_ID_V IS NULL   AND LBC1.LDE_ID =  :b1  AND LBC1.LDE_ID =  
  LBC2.LDE_ID  AND OBJ1.TRE_ID_O =  :b2  AND LBC1.FOUT =  0   


call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse       24      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute     26      0.04       0.04          0          0          0           0
Fetch       26   2414.90    2521.04     258210  624771631          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total       76   2414.95    2521.09     258210  624771631          0           0

Misses in library cache during parse: 2
Misses in library cache during execute: 2
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 64     (recursive depth: 2)

Rows     Row Source Operation
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=51 us)
      0   NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=47 us)
      0    NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=43 us)
      0     NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=42 us)
      0      NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=38 us)
      0       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECT (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=35 us)
      0        INDEX RANGE SCAN NGG_OBJ_TRE_FK_O_I (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=31 us)(object id 49947)
      0       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0        INDEX RANGE SCAN NGG_OBC_OBJ_FK_I (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49954)
      0      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0       INDEX RANGE SCAN NGG_OBC_BCT_FK_I (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49953)
      0     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_OBJECT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN NGG_OBJ_PK (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49964)
      0    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN NGG_LBC_PK (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49959)
      0   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)
      0    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN NGG_LBC_PK (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us)(object id 49959)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  direct path write temp                      17522        0.00          0.06
  direct path read temp                       17214        0.00          0.07
  latch: cache buffers chains                     1        0.00          0.00
```

Is this query producing a cartesian product? 
Why only on this particular database instance?

What more can I do to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Can you post the trace from the client trace with the explain plan, does the `rows` column also contain only 0 ?

Comment: Pasted the client trace into my question

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if that plan is what an EXPLAIN option in TKPROF generates rather than the actual execution plan as it runs.  Try capturing the query as it's run (or right as it fails) through querying AWR data or v$sql / v$sql_plan - see [this thread on asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:230338600346782894) for more.

(I say this because there's nothing in the plan as presented which would cause temp space to be used, assuming none of those are global temp tables)

Comment: The TKPROF reports are generated from 10046 trace files. 10046 trace files capture the actual execution statistics, which can only appear when the SQL statement actually executes.

Comment: 10046 (extended SQL) tracing shows execution statitics for waits; the TKPROF executable does have an EXPLAIN option, which is where explain plans for SQL statements may come from.  As I said, I don't see anything in the query using TEMP space, so might the plan in the TKPROF output not be the actual executed plan?  Bind variable peeking or session-level options could result in plan divergence.

Comment: See here:  http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2007/04/when-explanation-doesn-sound-quite.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, looking at this line  "`Fetch  26 2414.90 2521.04`" you can see almost all of the time is spent in CPU. This is backed up by the listed waits being just 0.06 and 0.07. Totally insignificant.

So this query plan is **NOTHING** to do with temp, and all to do with CPU.
Broadly, the query plan seems to follow the following join order.

```
SELECT OBC1.BCT_ID BCT_ID 
FROM  NGG_OBJECT OBJ1 
 join NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT OBC1 on (OBC1.OBJ_ID =  OBJ1.ID) 
 join NGG_OBJECTBASISCOMPONENT OBC2 on (OBC1.BCT_ID =  OBC2.BCT_ID ) 
 join NGG_OBJECT OBJ2 on (OBC2.OBJ_ID =  OBJ2.ID  ) 
 join NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT LBC1 on (OBC1.LBC_ID = LBC1.ID) 
 join NGG_LAAGBASISCOMPONENT LBC2 on (OBC2.LBC_ID = LBC2.ID)
WHERE OBJ1.TRE_ID_O =  :b2
  AND LBC1.LDE_ID =  LBC2.LDE_ID  
  AND OBJ1.ID >  OBJ2.ID  
  AND OBJ1.ODE_ID IS NULL 
  AND OBJ2.ODE_ID IS NULL   
  AND OBJ1.TRE_ID_V IS NULL   
  AND OBJ2.TRE_ID_V IS NULL   
  AND LBC1.LDE_ID =  :b1  
  AND LBC1.FOUT =  0
```

Given the lack of waits for disk reads, I suspect you've got all the indexes in memory, and probably the tables too. I suspect a lot of rows are matching that first TRE_ID_O filter and that each match is then hitting the NGG_OBJECT table and possibly getting excluded by either of the OBJ1.ODE_ID IS NULL / OBJ1.TRE_ID_V IS NULL conditions (or both).

What are the table volumes ? Are there in the order of 10 million rows matching the TRE_ID_O value.

I wouldn't be surprised if there was an alternative plan using hash joins (which would use temp)

Comment: The number of rows is not that great, about 10 thousand. This is reflected well in the first trace result. Somehow this particular database fetches this enormous amount of records. Looks like part of the where clause is not considered and a cartesian product is being created. I would not be surprised if we have hit yet another bug in the Oracle database.